What are the official positions of the various denominations on LLMs?
LLMs (Large Language Models), the technology behind ChatGPT, BingChat, Gemini, Mistral AI, etc., is on the rise, and the current and future generations will use this technology as a primary technology.
This prompts the question of what the official position of each denomination/church on the usage of LLM is.
(Note: I am looking for the official position of each church and denomination, not personal opinion.)

"The arithmetical machine produces effects which approach nearer to thought than all the actions of animals. But it does nothing which would enable us to attribute will to it, as to the animals." ~ Blaise Pascal. IMO this is just as applicable to LLMs as it was to his adding machine

the current and future generations will use this technology as a primary technology is still opinion. It's hyped/advertised to be used/useful, but I know plenty of people who don't use it and cases of it not being useful. I almost think this question is too early, as it's only been a few years and there are plenty of kinks to work out still from a purely tech standpoint.

@depperm This is a statistic for only ChatGPT:https://seo.ai/blog/how-many-users-does-chatgpt-have Also I think people greatly underestimate the impact of LLMs, but if a comparison is needed: It is a similar technological advance to social media or search engines like Google. Its practical implications are enormous and so I think that I can expect Christianity to make the first steps in forming an official opinion. This can lead to better guidance and demand, which might prevent some abominations that might be created.

@depperm Also what people might not realize yet, is that LLMs are simply a technology behind something like ChatGPT. Meaning there are quite a lot of ways where this tech can be integrated in. So I think there will be no escaping it unless you live off the grid. But I guess, yes, it is a prediction after all, so it is opinionated. However, if I look back to the various technological advances in the past decades, there is a pattern of wide spread adoption that I think can be applied to LLMs too.

I think it's way to early for an overview question on this topic and you should ask particular questions about denominations you might care about.  Answers are going to have to be unofficial because no ecclesial authorities are going to throw a council to address some silicon valley fad.  But there are some things, like Catholic Answer's virtual priest, which went over like a lead balloon.

as an aside, As they stand today, they certainly don't look like a primary technology, more like flavor of the month technology, and I've seen many of those come and go.
But as far as answering this question, it's seems too early to ask it, and you might as well ask what denominations think about using computers for obtaining answers, as far as I know, major denominations have no stand for or against computer use, in fact many use computers in their operations.

@scm-PersonalFriendofJesus LLM a flavor of the month? Currently, the only reason I see them "go" would be a replacement with something better. Like ICQ or MSN Messenger being replaced with Facebook and now TikTok. I would think that denominations have a position on Social Media and how to use it, given their high influence on people's relationships. LLMs will also have a huge impact on business, education, and yes human relationships, because they have the potential to "replace" humans as a booming market for AI-Friend, AI-Girlfriend market shows. So yes it's early, but also: Don't be slow!

@telion  Related to your question, the Pope has opinions on AI:  https://www.npr.org/2024/06/12/nx-s1-4950135/g7-pope-francis-ai-italy
